# How to Export Excel Charts from Data Table in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am looking for a way to Export Excel Charts from Data Table in VB.NET.
Manual i always use method Excel.Chart.SetSourceData(chartRange), 
Ex: chartRange: "A1:B5". But, I don't want to output Data from range "A1:B5" in excel file, only display Chart. I can do that?
Sorry for my english. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to export the chart as an image file or are you trying to create a chart programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to export an existing chart to an image file then you can use this:

```
xl.Sheets("Your sheet name").ChartObjects("Your chart name").Chart.Export(FileName:= _
        "C:\MyChart.GIF", FilterName:="GIF")
```

Comment: Could you please edit your post and be more specific with what you are trying to do? Based on the lack of answers, maybe know one else understands either.